# How to do animations in Android chess game

Tags: android, animation

I'm developing chess game for Android ([androidchess.appspot.com](http://androidchess.appspot.com)). If I want to add animations, should I use custom View extending Canvas (I do this now), or custom View extending SurfaceView?

Comment: I edited my response, adding some more information. (I'm using this comment in case you're relying on the "You have new responses" feature, which wouldn't notify you in case of an edited answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried using a `View` to extend `Canvas`, but for my game I'm using the same method as the LunarLander example game:

```
public class CustomView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

The usefulness of this is that it gives you handles for SurfaceHolder (so you can call up the canvas which is drawn to the screen), and the callbacks for `surfaceCreated`, `surfaceChanged` and `surfaceDestroyed`. That lets you do things like drawing a custom animation as soon as the surface is available or make sure that you don't try to draw to the canvas after it has been deactivated. Looking through LunarLander should show you how to use these properly.

---

Edit: I remembered another reason why using a SurfaceHolder was useful. This is because, as I mentioned above, it lets you get direct access to the canvas which is drawn to the screen. With a SurfaceHolder this is done not by overriding onDraw but by using something like `Canvas canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()`. (See LunarLander for exact syntax). The reason this is important is because it lets you control exactly when the drawing happens. If you can only work by overriding onDraw(), then the drawing doesn't happen until your program reaches a 'waiting' phase. In other words, you can't use `invalidate()` and `onDraw()` in a loop because the drawing won't happen until the loop finishes. And since you're likely to use loops for things like drawing a piece moving across the screen, this becomes a problem.

Note: It may be possible to avoid this problem by using multiple threads. I simply haven't tried that since it isn't required for my game; the only animation is has is fixed-length animations in response to user input rather than something continuously moving in the background, so I haven't experimented with multiple threads yet.

Comment: Thanks for help, I decided to use SurfaceView. BTW, can I find your game on the Market?

Comment: No problem. As for my game, it's nearly finished but not quite yet :)  It's a jigsaw puzzle game, fun but still simple enough to teach myself all the basics.