# How to position a view off-screen so that it can be Animated to move on-screen?

Tags: android, animation

I have a `RelativeLayout` filling the screen and a couple of `ImageView` positioned on it using `LayoutParams` margins. These `ImageView` are animated in different ways, and in one case I want an image to "fly in" to the screen from the right.

Unfortunately, if I set `leftMargin` for that ImageView greater than the width of the screen, it does not appear (or appears cropped if it partially visible at the start of animation).

I tried setting width and height of `RelativeLayout` to be bigger than screen size - it works, but only partially: if the image is positioned completely off-screen, it does not work, and if the image is partially visible, it is **not** cropped, but that works only for right and bottom sides.

So, my question is this: how to position several `ImageViews` on and **off** the screen so that I can animate them using `Animation`?

Comment: Ok, please post your solution if you have one. I'm currently having some trouble with animation as well, my animation goes along the wrong axis, don't know why yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I used a trick: I combined AnimationDrawable and view animation. I did the following (assuming that the animation has to run T milliseconds):

1. Position that ImageView on-screen.
2. Set as its background an AnimationDrawable with following frames:

   - empty Drawable: 1ms,
   - normal Drawable: Tms.
3. Change view's animation to this:

   - jump to off-screen position (translation with duration=1ms),
   - do normal animation.

Comment: have you implemented it? Would be nice to check some code out!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good place to start looking for those who would use Fixpoint's solution.

[Android — How to position View off-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554871/android-how-to-position-view-off-screen)