# Custom animated menu in Android

Tags: android, animation, menu

I'm doing a new Android application right now and I would like to do some new menu instead of standard buttons. I make a project like this:

[image: menu]

I would like to have several images (max 3 at the same time on the screen) and I would like to move from one to another using drag up and down gesture (like standart ScrollView). I would like to have active option bigger than another (image 2 on the picture) with some text and I would like to move pictures on circular path (red line on picture).

I have idea - make several pictures in List, add animations to them and then move them after gestures , but this is very complicated and maybe you have better idea, and I don't know how to achive the same effect like in ScrollView - fast gesture move more options than slow one.

And ideas? The best will be similar examples.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is easier to do if you are looking for existing approaches/libraries that implement the [Carousel](http://4ourth.com/wiki/Carousel) UI pattern:

- Here is an article that explains it in code: [Android 3D Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel). It looks very similar to your screenshot (active item appears bigger, others are arranged circularly in the background). And based on this, here is the vertical implementation: [Android-VerticalCarousel](https://github.com/rameshkec85/Android-VerticalCarousel)
- Here is one approach that looks like it supports many different variations of a Carousel: [carousel-layout-android](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/).

Since your screenshot shows a menu that is partially off-screen, you could use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222919/1140682) to achieve that.